# Hide layers vs adding layers (WMS or WMTS)

Tags: visibility, openlayers-3, wms

I am creating a web map that will contain at the moment 12 layers (different layers from the same WMS or WMTS service.

Of those layers, only up to 3-4 at a time will be shown, the others will not be visible unless the user enables them.

The question is: would it be better to 
1. include all the hidden layers in the mapLayers array with *visible* set to false and use setVisible to show/hide layers or
2. removing/adding a layer every time a user disables a layer/enables another?

My concerns are mainly from a performance perspective but explanations about other motivations are also welcome.

I have tried taking a snapshot with the profiler in Chrome dev tools and it looks like the size of it is not related to the presence/absence of the hidden layers.